# Dynamically sized nested elements with fixed padding

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, combobox

The following HTML makes a pretty clean foundation for a 200px wide, 30px high editable combobox that can be used with angular binding or some other JavaScript data-binding. However, I want the outer-most div to be 100% wide, and the 180px wide div to use padding instead of an explicit size. However, padding always seems to be ignored. Does anyone know why this is, and if there are any good work-arounds? (preferably CSS/HTML)

```
<style>
    .comboboxOuterDiv {
        padding:0px; 
        margin:0px; 
        border:0px; 
        height:30px; 
        width:200px; 
        position:relative;
    }
    .comboboxSelectDiv {
         height:100%; 
         width:100%; 
         position:absolute; 
         top:0px; 
         left:0px; 
         z-index:0;
    }
    .comboboxSelect {
        height:100%; 
        width:100%; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px;
    }
    .comboboxTextDiv {
        height:100%; 
        width:180px; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px; 
        z-index:1;
    }
    .comboboxText {
         height:100%; 
         width:100%; 
         position:absolute; 
         top:0px; 
         left:0px; 
    }
</style>
<div class="comboboxOuterDiv">
    <div class="comboboxSelectDiv">
        <select class="comboboxSelect">
            <option value="a_value">A Value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="comboboxTextDiv">
        <input class="comboboxText" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better to use separate css code ... all of your styles are inline in html tags and really I'm confused ...

Comment: A cleaner version is now posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example for anyone interested:

```
<style>
    .comboboxOuterDiv {
        padding:0px; 
        margin:0px; 
        border:0px; 
        height:30px; 
        width:100%; 
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .comboboxSelectDiv {
         height:100%; 
         width:100%; 
         position:relative; 
         top:0px; 
         left:0px; 
         z-index:0;
    }
    .comboboxSelect {
        height:100%; 
        width:100%; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px;
    }
    .comboboxTextDiv {
        display:block;
        height:100%; 
        width:auto; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0px; 
        left:0px; 
        right:20px;
        z-index:1;
    }
    .comboboxText {
         height:100%; 
         width:100%; 
         position:absolute; 
         top:0px; 
         left:0px; 
    }
</style>
<div class="comboboxOuterDiv">
    <div class="comboboxSelectDiv">
        <select class="comboboxSelect">
            <option value="a_value">A Value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="comboboxTextDiv">
        <input class="comboboxText" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please delete this answer... we can see your edit on the main question

Comment: This answer is different than the edit. This answer works. The edit doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code!

probably it is your goal!! check it and tell me about that!

## Demo on jsfiddle

i changed `height` of `comboboxText` class to `80%`

and

`width` of `comboboxTextDiv` class to a non percentage value , such as `auto`

Comment: I was looking for the comboOuterDiv to dynamically change size without the arrow portion on the right changing. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @AaronF oh :D ... it occurred because of `comboboxTextDiv` class!

Comment: i saw your answer and it is complete, so! you don't need to my answer ;)

Comment: It's all good. Thanks for putting in the time to help me out!